# (GPS & MySQL) No module error in python 2.7 with virtualenv running on Lubuntu

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed the gps packages and the mysql packages using :
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd
&
sudo apt-get install python2.7-mysqldb
it shows that the packages have been successfully installed but when i run my python code which has :

```
import gps 
import MySQLdb as mdb
error comes:
ImportError: No module named gps
and ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
in python sys.path gives the following:
sys.path
['', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/src/django-tastypie-master', '/home/odroid/barc/workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/barc/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

% SOLVED, if python is running in a virtual env then there is a issue with  the path of the modules. need to change path :

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages % this command has to be made everytime the terminal window is closed
and for permanently implementing this change// 
source vim .bashrc
% copy //export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
% and then 
source .bashrc